# The idiomatic antonyms of "keep someone in the loop"?

Tags: phrase-request, idiomatic-language, colloquial-language

In [this thread](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/339263/10484) I realized that 'loop someone in' does not fit in the scenario of inviting someone into a WhatsApp group for an intermittent discussion, and the idiomatic expression should be 'keep someone in the loop'.

But how to express that opposite? For instance, someone is too annoying in the group sending irrelevant messages now and then, and the moderator just removes them from the chat group. Are the following phrases appropriate?

1. leave someone out of the loop
2. cut someone out of the loop
3. take someone out of the loop
4. remove someone out of the loop

Or there are more native ways to talk about it?

Comment: #4 is non-idiomatic. #2 and #3 are equally acceptable, and obviously different to #1 in that it makes a difference if the person ***is currently*** in the loop (you can't sensibly ***take** him **out** of the loop* if he was never in the loop to begin with).

Comment: But "leaving someone out of the loop" would be an odd way to deal with the fact that he sends irrelevant messages now and then. Either the guy is supposed to be kept informed or he isn't. If the moderator doesn't like irrelevant messages, there's no reason why he should allow the troublesome person to be allowed to post messages at all. But he can still be kept informed of any discussions and decisions. I think you're still mistakenly assuming that to be kept in the loop means to be invited to participate in discussions (it *doesn't*). It means ***to be kept informed***, as repeatedly stated.

Comment: There are lots of alternative idioms like *keep in the dark* or even more extremely *send to Coventry*.

Comment: To loop somebody in is used. Like in spy movies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question:

You've got the right idea with your phrases.  There isn't a separate common idiom for not keeping someone updated.

1. "leave someone out of the loop" - this is OK, but could imply they were never in the loop, or that you are looking at current members and "cleaning up."
2. "cut someone out of the loop" - OK - *cut* is a strong word, meaning someone very much wanted X out of the loop.
3. "take someone out of the loop" - OK, and neutral tone.
4. "remove someone out of the loop" - Better said "remove from the loop" - OK, and neutral tone.

Some relevant information:

*Keeping X in the loop* means to keep X informed with periodic updates.

If periodic updates are in a WhatsApp group, adding X to the group will enable X to *stay in the loop.*

But other things could keep X in the loop as well, such as someone relaying X information every once in a while, etc.  Therefore, if you want X *out of the loop*, you may need to do more than just remove them from the WhatsApp group, unless the WhatsApp group is the only source of that information.